# XMonad not launching xmobar

Tags: window-manager, xmonad

For some reason, my xmonad config won't launch xmobar, but it doesn't throw any errors, and the command `xmobar` launches it fine. Here is my `xmobar.hs`

```haskell
 import XMonad
 import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
 import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
 import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)

 main = do
     xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar"
     xmonad $ defaultConfig
         { terminal    = "terminator"
         , layoutHook = avoidStruts $ layoutHook defaultConfig
         , manageHook=manageHook defaultConfig <+> manageDocks
         , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP $ sjanssenPP { ppOrder = reverse }
         , borderWidth = 1
         }
```

Comment: Does it work withe the full path? Eg., `xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar ~/.xmobar.hs"`

Comment: Doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: You are also using `manageDocks`, so perhaps you need the `-d` (start as dock) option to see it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It closes immediately because you aren't sending anything to it. You need to specify the output for the pretty print :

```
    dynamicLogWithPP $ sjanssenPP {ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc},
```